# How to diagnose this Kubernetes pod high load

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes

I am executing a Jenkins pod instance in IBM Cloud kubernetes service. I am getting a very high load even though none of the processes has high load. I have read that it has to do with IO requests. The work disk is mounted as a Persistent Volume (NFS). I am using ibmc-file-retain-bronze storage class. Do I need to use silver or gold?

The task Jenkins is doing is about building a React (node) application. It takes hours to finish.
How can I diagnose and find out what the problem is?

This is how my "top" looks:

```
top - 22:20:43 up  7:42,  0 users,  load average: 4.13, 4.25, 4.01
Tasks:   8 total,   1 running,   7 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  1.2 us,  0.5 sy,  0.0 ni, 67.9 id, 30.1 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.3 st
KiB Mem :  4045168 total,   483248 free,  1281296 used,  2280624 buff/cache
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 free,        0 used.  2697240 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                             
 2897 root      20   0 1340872 226024  21672 S   0.7  5.6   1:23.71 node                                                                                
    5 root      20   0 3621112 690624  28188 S   0.3 17.1   1:59.56 java                                                                                
    1 root      20   0    1152      8      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.29 tini                                                                                
  354 root      20   0   20024   3900   3272 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.03 bash                                                                                
 2609 root      20   0   48616   3156   2764 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.00 su                                                                                  
 2610 jenkins   20   0   18200   3368   2820 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.00 bash                                                                                
 2652 root      20   0   19808   3292   2908 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.00 bash                                                                                
 3106 jenkins   20   0   41052   3252   2764 R   0.0  0.1   0:00.00 top
```

Comment: Load is tracked at the kernel level, not the pod. You might also find this useful: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/116849/4358

Comment: To try to find the issue I had created a new node in the kubernetes cluster and started only the Jenkins pod there, and the result is the same... no other processes from other pods generating that load. I'll have a look that that link. thanks.

Comment: It is not the answer to the question, but in my specific case, moving from bronze storage class to gold one in IBM Cloud storage service seems to have solved the problem.